# Why is there 8 byte padding of "0xcc" between aligned ints on the stack? C++ 32 bit Windows 7

Tags: c++, variables, stack, local, padding

```
int p;
int i1;
int i2;
i1 = 1 << 16;
i2 = 1 << 8;
p = int(&i1)+3;

cout << hex;
cout << "&i1: " << int(&i1) << endl;
cout << "&i2: " << int(&i2) << endl;
for(int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
  cout << p << ": " << uint(*((byte*)p--)) << endl;
```

> #### Output:
>
> ```
> &i1: 12fac8
> &i2: 12fabc
> 12facb: 0
> 12faca: 1
> 12fac9: 0
> 12fac8: 0
> 12fac7: cc
> 12fac6: cc
> 12fac5: cc
> 12fac4: cc
> 12fac3: cc
> 12fac2: cc
> 12fac1: cc
> 12fac0: cc
> 12fabf: 0
> 12fabe: 0
> 12fabd: 1
> 12fabc: 0
> ```

I'm running Windows 7 32 bit, using Visual Studio 2010. Not much else to say but stackoverflow won't let me post without more "details" so this is just useless rambling :)

Comment: Most likely the compiler inserting some padding. If it looks at the padding bytes after your code runs, and finds that the values have changed, it can alert you to the fact that something has written outside boundaries. At least in most cases I've seen, compiling with optimization turned on (e.g., Release mode) eliminates this.

Comment: @JerryCoffin is'nt `p = int(&i1)+3;` UB? because of `uint(*((byte*)p--))`

Answer (score 3):

When you compile code in Visual C with the `/GZ` option, all uninitialised stack variables are set using the `0xcc` pattern (to assist debugging, I suspect).

Hence those bytes in there are probably the `p` and `i` integers <sup>(a)</sup>, or temporaries created by the *bizarre* method of using an `int` as a pointer, something you may want to rethink.

In any case, *why* they're there is irrelevant at your particular abstraction level, the C++ "virtual machine". An implementation is free to organise the stack however it wants for efficiency, inserting padding where needed.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> Despite the fact `i` is declared later on in the code, there's nothing stopping the installation allocating space for it at function entry. Most things happening under the cover can be surprising like this since the "as if" rule is what governs how an implementation works. It can do whatever it wants provided the *effect* matches what is in the standard.

Answer (score 1):

The 0xcc comes from when you run in debug build. This is done because you can recognize this pattern easy when you are bug hunting for buffer overflows etc

Answer (score 1):

It is either padding, or unused temporary variables. In MSVC with debug builds, the compiler generates code to fill all variables with `0xcc` bytes. This helps identify unused variables - and the choice of `cc` is not a random pick, it helps because it's an almost impossible address to get from the OS, and it also is the `int 3` instruction, so if you where to suddenly find a way to execute that code (e.g. a function pointer to somewhere in the data), the code will stop then and there. Having debugged a few "runaway code" problems, I find that a very useful feature.

The fact that it is a rather high (or negative) number is also beneficial, since it often shows up "use of variable as index or pointer" by making it an invalid access, rather than, say, if it was zero which would be a valid index into an array, for example.